# Android Studio - Shortcut to close floating Logcat window?

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I have added a shortcut to Android Studio to show my Logcat window ( you can do that under `Keymap` -> `Tool Windows`) which usually is in floating mode.

So when I press my shortcut, it appears, which is nice.

I would love to also hide it again with a shortcut (preferably the same), but there doesn't seem to be an option for that. Or do I miss something?

Comment: For me the default hotkey show and hides the logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out myself: It works in all modes except `Float`. The windowed mode basically works the same way, so when switching to that, the shortcut opens AND closes the window as expected.